# why does my form show to fill in all fields even though I filled them

Tags: php, authentication

So this is my code, and I have no idea what I did wrong. The result of whatever it is that I did wrong is that every time I try to login with both of the fields filled, that is to say, that I have a password and a username entered, I get an error message saying to please fill in all fields, as though I hadn't filled one of them.

**login.php**

```
include_once 'header.php';
?>
           
 <section class="signup-form" style="text-align:center;">
     <h2>Log In</h2>
     
     <form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
         
         <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username/Email">
         
         <br><br>
         
         <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
         
         <br><br>
         
         <button type="submit" name="submit">Log In</button>
     </form>
     
      <?php
  if(isset($_GET["error"])){
      
      if($_GET["error"] == "empty input") {
          
          echo "<p style='color:red; text-align:center;'>Please fill in all fields!</p>";
          
      }
     
       if($_GET["error"] == "wronglogin") {
          
          echo "<p style='color:red; text-align:center;'>wrong login info. Try again</p>";
          
      }
    
      
      
  }
  ?>
 </section>
```

**login.inc.php**

```
    <?php 

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    
    $username = $_POST['uid'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
    
    require_once 'dbh.inc.php';
    require_once "functions.inc.php";
    
     if (emptyInputLogin($username, $pwd) !== false) {
        
         header('location: ../login.php?error=empty input');
        exit();
    }
loginUser($conn, $username, $pwd);

}
else {
    
    header('location: ../login.php');
    exit();
}
```

**functions.inc.php**

```
 function emptyInputLogin( $username, $pwd ) {

$result;
if (empty($username) || empty($pwd)){
    
    $result = false;
    
} 

return $result;

}
```

Comment: I think this is the problem `if(emptyInputLogin($username, $pwd) !== false)`

Comment: You need to show the function `emptyInputLogin`

Comment: Review the function **emptyInputLogin($username, $pwd)** .... Seems it's returning **true**

Comment: Why was this question upvoted (twice even) when it's missing key information, like the code that does the actual check they are asking about?

Comment: You need to return the value from the function `return $result;` or it will always evaluate as `null`, which will make `!== false` always to be true. https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't notice that I was missing the function, I added it now.

Comment: Magnus Eriksson, do I do that from within the function? I did that inside the function and the result didn't change

Comment: Not within the `if` statement, outside of it.

Comment: Just add it as the last line in the function (outside of the if-statement). You should also set `$result = false;` instead of just `$result;` when you define the variable in the beginning of the function, or it will never return `false`.

Comment: okay, I changed $result to false, and added return $result to the function, outside of the if statement... it didn't fix the problem, even when I reloaded the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return `true` if any of them are empty and `false` if they are not.

```
function emptyInputLogin( $username, $pwd ) {
    $result = false; // default value to return

    if (empty($username) || empty($pwd)){
        $result = true;
    } 

    return $result;
}
```

This function can also be written as:

```
function emptyInputLogin( $username, $pwd ) {
    return empty($username) || empty($pwd);
}
```

since `empty($username) || empty($pwd)` will evaluate as true/false.

Your if-statement can also be changed to just

```
if (emptyInputLogin($username, $pwd))
```

which makes it easier to read.

Or even easier, skip the function altogether in your `login.inc.php` file:

```
if (empty($username) || empty($pwd)) {
    header('location: ../login.php?error=empty input');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: @sketchmanluke - `loginUser()` is not a native PHP function. You need to write your own authentication system (or use a framework that has it ready to use since authentication can easily be insecure if you don't know what you're doing). There are many many different ways of authenticating users, so it would be impossible for PHP to have a generic "loginUser()" function.